# Gson fromJson Method Returning null Parsing Stripe API Response

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am calling this method when I receive my response from Stripe backend API. When I call the fromJson function the returned value is null. I cannot see what I am doing wrong here? I am using OkHttp for the API call and when I log the value of responseBody.string() I get a clear JSON string.

```
val gson = Gson()
val type: Type = object : TypeToken<Map<String, Any>?>() {}.type
val jsonMap: Map<String, Any> = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), type)
```

Here is the response from the API but have removed sensitive data:

```json
{ 
   "id":"cus_XXXXXXXXXXX",
   "object":"customer",
   "address":null,
   "balance":0,
   "created":1575563900,
   "currency":null,
   "default_source":null,
   "delinquent":false,
   "description":null,
   "discount":null,
   "email":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "invoice_prefix":"XXXXXXXX",
   "invoice_settings":{ 
      "custom_fields":null,
      "default_payment_method":null,
      "footer":null
   },
   "livemode":true,
   "metadata":{ 

   },
   "name":null,
   "phone":null,
   "preferred_locales":[ 

   ],
   "shipping":null,
   "sources":{ 
      "object":"list",
      "data":[ 

      ],
      "has_more":false,
      "total_count":0,
      "url":"/v1/customers/cus_XXXXXXXXXXX/sources"
   },
   "subscriptions":{ 
      "object":"list",
      "data":[ 

      ],
      "has_more":false,
      "total_count":0,
      "url":"/v1/customers/cus_XXXXXXXXXXX/subscriptions"
   },
   "tax_exempt":"none",
   "tax_ids":{ 
      "object":"list",
      "data":[ 

      ],
      "has_more":false,
      "total_count":0,
      "url":"/v1/customers/cus_XXXXXXXXXXX/tax_ids"
   },
   "tax_info":null,
   "tax_info_verification":null
}
```

Edit: I have now created a data class for the response however when changing my code I am still receiving null as my customer object.

```
data class StripeCustomer(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @SerializedName("object") val obj: String?,
    @SerializedName("address") val address: String?,
    @SerializedName("balance") val balance: Any,
    @SerializedName("created") val created: Any,
    @SerializedName("currency") val currency: Any,
    @SerializedName("default_source") val defaultSource: Any,
    @SerializedName("delinquent") val delinquent: Any,
    @SerializedName("description") val description: Any,
    @SerializedName("discount") val discount: Any,
    @SerializedName("email") val email: String?,
    @SerializedName("invoice_prefix") val invoicePrefix: Any,
    @SerializedName("invoice_settings") val invoiceSettings: Any,
    @SerializedName("livemode") val livemode: Any,
    @SerializedName("metadata") val metadata: Any,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: Any,
    @SerializedName("phone") val phone: Any,
    @SerializedName("preferred_locales") val preferredLocales: Any,
    @SerializedName("shipping") val shipping: Any,
    @SerializedName("sources") val sources: Any,
    @SerializedName("subscriptions") val subscriptions: Any,
    @SerializedName("tax_exempt") val taxExempt: Any,
    @SerializedName("tax_ids") val taxIds: Any,
    @SerializedName("tax_info") val taxInfo: Any,
    @SerializedName("tax_info_verification") val taxInfoVerification: Any
)
```

Edited Gson Functions:

```
val gson = Gson()
val customerObject = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), StripeCustomer::class.java)
val customerId = customerObject.id ?: return@subscribe
```

API Code:

I am using the Stripe Example Project as shown below:

```
interface BackendApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("ephemeral_keys")
    fun createEphemeralKey(@FieldMap apiVersionMap: HashMap<String, String>): Observable<ResponseBody>

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create_customer")
    fun createCustomer(@FieldMap emailMap: HashMap<String, String>): Observable<ResponseBody>

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create_payment_intent")
    fun createPaymentIntent(@FieldMap params: MutableMap<String, Any>): Observable<ResponseBody>

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create_setup_intent")
    fun createSetupIntent(@FieldMap params: HashMap<String, Any>): Observable<ResponseBody>
}

internal class BackendApiFactory internal constructor(private val backendUrl: String) {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(Settings(context).backendUrl)

    fun create(): BackendApi {
        // Set your desired log level. Use Level.BODY for debugging errors.
        // Adding Rx so the calls can be Observable, and adding a Gson converter with
        // leniency to make parsing the results simple.
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
            .build()

        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(backendUrl)
            .client(httpClient)
            .build()
            .create(BackendApi::class.java)
    }

    private companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 15L
    }
}
```

--------- LATEST EDIT ---------

```
compositeDisposable.add(backendApi.createCustomer(hashMapOf("email" to currentUserEmail))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .subscribe({ stripeCustomer ->

                                val customerId = stripeCustomer.id ?: return@subscribe
                                println(customerId)
```

**...**

The above shows the api being called with the changes suggested

Below is the changed BackendApi interface.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create_customer")
    fun createCustomer(@FieldMap emailMap: HashMap<String, String>): Observable<StripeCustomer>
```

Returns the following stack trace:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.StripeCustomer
        for method BackendApi.createCustomer
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:52)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:115)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:82)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:37)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:149)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy0.createCustomer(Unknown Source)
        at com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.EphemeralKeyProvider$createEphemeralKey$1.onSuccess(EphemeralKeyProvider.kt:45)
        at com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.EphemeralKeyProvider$createEphemeralKey$1.onSuccess(EphemeralKeyProvider.kt:21)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.StripeCustomer declares multiple JSON fields named invoice_prefix
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:64)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:113)
        at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:82) 
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:37) 
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170) 
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:149) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006) 
        at $Proxy0.createCustomer(Unknown Source) 
        at com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.EphemeralKeyProvider$createEphemeralKey$1.onSuccess(EphemeralKeyProvider.kt:45) 
        at com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.EphemeralKeyProvider$createEphemeralKey$1.onSuccess(EphemeralKeyProvider.kt:21) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Make Model of the json from api. use json to java model plugins in android studio for generating models. Instead of passing map to Type Token pass that model. Your data will be flled in model

Comment: I don't get why you are trying to put your model into a Map. You should define a data class with GSON annotations to map your model

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `data` model to parse data from json`.

First, Create model like below:

```
data class StripeCustomer(
    @SerializedName("custom_fields")
    var invoiceSettings: InvoiceSettings,
    @SerializedName("preferred_locales")
    var preferredLocales: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("sources")
    var sources: Sources,
    @SerializedName("subscriptions")
    var subscriptions: Sources,
    @SerializedName("tax_ids")
    var taxIds: Sources,
    @SerializedName("tax_info")
    var taxInfo: String?,
    @SerializedName("tax_info_verification")
    var taxInfoVerification: String?,
    @SerializedName("tax_exempt")
    var taxExempt: String?,
    @SerializedName("shipping")
    var shipping: String?,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    var phone: String?,
    @SerializedName("invoice_prefix")
    var name: String?,
    @SerializedName("livemode")
    var livemode: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("invoice_prefix")
    var invoicePrefix: String?,
    @SerializedName("email")
    var email: String?,
    @SerializedName("discount")
    var discount: String?,
    @SerializedName("description")
    var description: String?,
    @SerializedName("delinquent")
    var delinquent: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("default_source")
    var defaultSource: String?,
    @SerializedName("currency")
    var currency: String?,
    @SerializedName("created")
    var created: Long?,
    @SerializedName("balance")
    var balance: Int?,
    @SerializedName("address")
    var address: String?,
    @SerializedName("object")
    var objectType: String?,
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: String?
)

data class InvoiceSettings (
    @SerializedName("custom_fields")
    var customFields: String?,
    @SerializedName("default_payment_method")
    var defaultPaymentMethod: String?,
    @SerializedName("footer")
    var footer: String?
)

data class Sources (
    @SerializedName("object")
    var objects: String?,
    @SerializedName("data")
    var data: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("has_more")
    var hasMore: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("total_count")
    var totalCount: Int?,
    @SerializedName("url")
    var url: String?
)
```

Then convert `json` to `StripeCustomer` like below:

```
val gson = Gson()
val stripeCustomer = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), StripeCustomer::class.java)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my code to the above snippets you provided however Im still getting null?

Comment: Yh sure, as mentioned in edit, I have already used this backend code for iOS app and it works great, just not sure why the gson function keeps returning a null object!

Comment: No, I want the Android part that you used to fetch data from server

Comment: From using which one you get that data?

Comment: createCustomer - Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Then change it to get `StripeCustomer` like below: `fun createCustomer(@FieldMap emailMap: HashMap<String, String>): Observable<StrieCustomer >`. It will directly give you `StripeCustomer` instead of `ResponseBody`

Comment: ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.fisherassociates.mt18academy.Controllers.StripeCheckout.StripeCustomer for method BackendApi.createCustomer```     Thats the crash I got in Log when I just changed that?

Comment: You have already added the converter `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`

Comment: Thats right, in BackendApiFactory. I will add an edit to show what I have done